# Critical Issue with Kendo UI Grid (post 2013 Q1 release)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

take a look at these 2 fiddles

http://jsfiddle.net/uFcHK/ 
(v2013.1.319)

http://jsfiddle.net/rcvY3/ 
(v2013.2.716)

The code is identical.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
        },
        pageSize: 15,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true
    },

    height: 450,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    editable: true,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    filterable: false,
    columns: ["ProductID", "ProductName", "UnitPrice"]
});
```

(you can ignore  the the broken nav panel, I don't see this in prod)

The problem is the record count.

If you click on "Add new record" you will see the record count do a text add instead of number add.  This is crazy, no idea how kendo let this slide for half a year+

Comment: In my experience, Telerik has decent support forms.  Sounds like you need to report this issue there.

Comment: You need a premium account to post there.  They encourage people to post to SO for free support.

Comment: btw: the problem with the styles is because you mix different version of KendoUI. You also use a non supported version of jQuery *BUT* this is not what is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai, indeed.  In prod, I have all things worked out fine, but the record count issue stands.  I have not been able to upgrade the kendo js past v2013.1.319.  I check every release in hope they would fix this.  But they are oblivious.

Comment: The problem seems to be related with `odata`. Kendo UI has a service returning the same data but as JSONP and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I was actually looking at the fiddle from your site.  You are using the latest KUI, and not having this issue.  Seems the only diff maybe the Odata, which is what I use in my env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `OData` that return `total` as `string` since this is received as `string`.

In previous releases of code the increment was done as `total++` but now it is being added a `number` allowing to add more than one record in one single operation. The problem is that if you do `string` + `number` you actually get the `number` concatenated to the `string`.

The easiest way of solving it is providing a `total` function that just converts the `string` to `number` something as simple as defining in the `DataSource`:

```
dataSource: {
    type           : "odata",
    transport      : {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
    },
    schema : {
        total : function (data) {
            // Convert __count to number
            return +data.d.__count;
        }
    },
    pageSize       : 15,
    serverPaging   : true,
    serverSorting  : true,
    serverFiltering: true
},
```

Comment: Great work OnaBai.  I hope kendo pays you for fixing their stuff :)